# PHP array into individual php string, from SQL data

Tags: php, sql

Here is a PHP code, that can be used to count data from SQL.
This code displays the data in a table, I want to convert these table values (or arrays) into individual php strings. How can I do that ?
I tried many methods, main issue is my  lack of proper knowledge in PHP. I hope someone will help !

```
<?php
    $hostname="your_hostname";
    $username="your_username";
    $password="your_password";
    $db = "your_dbname";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT country,COUNT(*)
    FROM author
    GROUP BY country') as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    ?>
```

and the result is

```
+-----------+----------+
| country   | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+----------+
| Australia |        2 | 
| Brazil    |        1 | 
| Canada    |        2 | 
| Germany   |        1 | 
| India     |        1 | 
| UK        |        4 | 
| USA       |        4 | 
+-----------+----------+
```

I want to use php string to use it anywhere else in the script/page.
For example if I use `$Australia` or `$value[0]` , the string value should be "`2`", how can I achieve that ?

Comment: _Small Hint_ If you use an alias on `COUNT(*)` the row name is easier to make use of. So `... COUNT(*) as cnt...` and the `$row['cnt']`

Comment: If you want to use the data from this query again later in the code. Put all the rows into an array, use `->fetchAll()` and that does exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current approach you can create a new array in your `foreach`, then use that array elsewhere.

```
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT country,COUNT(*) FROM author GROUP BY country') as $row) {
    $countries[$row['country']] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

elsewhere you'd use `$countries['Australia']`. You could use `strtolower` as well so keys are easier to match up.

Another approach though may be using [`fetchall`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT country,COUNT(*) FROM author GROUP BY country');
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    //same iteration as before
}
```

with this approach you won't necessarily know the `key`s. If you want the country with most/least views though this could be easier.

Comment: actually I used countries as example. There will be no countries, instead I want to collect data of last 10 days. How can I do that, sorry to make it complicated.

Comment: @Haamaa So in that case... Ask a question that states that as the goal. Show us what you have written so far that does not quite work and we will be able to help you with that question. If you dont ask the right question you cannot expect to get the right answer

Comment: This appears to answer the question **as asked**, perfectly well.

Comment: @Haamaa Same concept, just change column names.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sure, I will mark this as the answer because you answered for my requirements. I will post another in detail and will post  the link here. kindly answer that if you have time.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, can you please try and answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457243